# How to create header in MS Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, headers

How to create header in MS Excel? So they will not move while I am scrolling the page and will not be affected when I am sorting any column.

Till now I use: select row, go to `View` > `Freeze Panes` > `Freeze top row`

It scrolls just fine:

[image]

But when I'm trying to sort by first column excel is sorting including top row:

[image]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

In the sort dialog box check the option **My data has headers**

[image]